# Reasons there were no Super Star Destroyers during the Thrawn Trilogy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Were there any reasons in-universe and out of universe the Empire didn't use Super Star Destroyers during the events of the Thrawn Trilogy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The out-of-universe explanation is due to a combination of it not yet being established that the *Executor* was not a unique vessel - it was not until after Zahn began his trilogy that other authors utilised *Super*-class vessels, themselves recently retconned to fix the size inconsistencies - and the simple fact that Zahn prefers small-scale tactical military sci-fi to large-scale strategic sci-fi. Another great example of this is his *Blackcollar* trilogy, which focuses on ground combat rather than space combat, despite the latter being more important to the overall war in the story.

In-universe the retconned explanation has been that [Thrawn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mitth%27raw%27nuruodo) (scroll down to "Final return to the galaxy"), while gaining the loyalty of the Moff Council, did not actually gain the loyalty of the majority of the Imperial military, which stayed loyal to local warlords. Several of those warlords, such as [Warlord Zsinj](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zsinj) from *Iron Fist* and *The Courtship of Princess Leia*, had *Super*-class vessels, but the loyalist military that flocked to Thrawn did not. This makes Thrawn extending Imperial control over half the galaxy even more impressive.

Comment: I didn't know about any SSD retcon.  Do you have a link by any chance?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Star_Destroyer

Comment: also until recently weren't there only 4 Executor Class SSDs? Lusankya, Iron Fist, Razor's Kiss, and Executor

Comment: I’m sure it’s always been considered there was more than one SSD. In ROTJ Han says “there are a lot of command ships” in reference to The Executor. I had a book as a kid, some kind of technical manual, possibly non-canon even then, that said there were a total of six SSDs.